# clang-format comprehensive example

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there an C++ example file that demonstrates available clang-format feature?  I was curious what would represent the most compact example of code that generates a unique output for every option combination.

Comment: You can try using your own code, or code from an open-source library.  Setting clang-format options so they suit your coding style should take a few days of trial and error.

Comment: What about numeric options like `ColumnLimit`? It would be very difficult to have unique output for every setting of `ColumnLimit`, as there are 2^31 possible settings.